# PhpStorm7 css autocomplete not working

Tags: php, css, phpstorm

I've been using the PhpStorm suggestions (ctrl + space) for months, until some day ago it stopped working on css classes.

I type for example `<div class="` and then hit `ctrl + space`, but it always says "No suggestions".

I've configured in `Settings/Directories` as `Resource Root` the folders that contain the css files. What should i do to have suggestions pop up again? What could be the cause?

Comment: First of all -- try `File | Invalidate caches...` and restart IDE.

Comment: did you save the file as .css file??

Comment: does invalidating caches help? If it doesn't, please check if your .css files are included in your .html (php?) via <link> tag. Note also that selectors completion from linked css files doesn't work if there is embedded CSS (<style> tag) in HTML file